# How to echo variable name to batch file so the destination file can use the variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am building a batch file. I want the batch file to be generated, so I echo some lines to a batch file. The problem is the following:

I have generate.bat and backup.bat. When I start generate.bat, I gather some user info and save that to backup.bat. In backup.bat I gather the date and the time. I save that in a variable. How is it possible to save a variable name into that backup.bat, so it can be used in backup.bat

```
set /P ALOCATION=First loc.%=%
set /P BLOCATION=Second loc. %=%

echo robocopy "%ALOCATION%" "%BLOCATION%%thatpath%" /E /xd "%ALOCATION:~0,3%$Recycle.Bin" >> backup.bat
```

I already have some code in backup.bat:

```
SET thatpath=%name%
```

After this set that I echo the robocopy mentioned above. I, however, want it to use the "thatpath" every time the backup.bat is started.

So to be short:
I have a generate.bat, I echo a line to backup.bat, and I would like the line to use a variable in backup.bat. I don't want it to be used in generate.bat, I just want it to be used when starting backup.bat

Comment: What is the `%=%` portion intended for??

Comment: @aschipfl I just found that good looking :P. Do you maybe know how I can echo %%a? I now know how to echo %a%, how can I do %%a?

Comment: I think this topic could be worth a new question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by using `echo %%variable%%`. It then will be useful for the other batch file.

Comment: How can I do so if a variable is %%a for example?

Comment: Exactly the same way: use a double "%%" for every "%" you want to output. So `echo %%%%a`

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, this is true as long as you are *not* in the scope of a `for %%a` loop, in which case it became `%`, followed by the currently iteration value of `%%a`; if you are in the scope of the loop, you could do `set "VAR=%%%%a"` before the loop, then expand `VAR` inside of the loop using [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) like `!VAR!`; alternatively, you could wrap around another loop like `for %%b in (%%%%a) do for %%a in (...) do echo %%b`...

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, Perhaps you are interested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41365237) concerning securely echoing `%%a`...