# How to securely echo literal string "%I"?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

How can I echo the string `%I` in a secure way, independent on whether or not the `echo` command line is placed within a `for %I` loop?

For example, in command prompt (`cmd`):

```cmd
>>> rem // `echo` is outside of `for` scope, so this works:

>>> echo %I
%I

>>> rem // `echo` is inside of `for` scope, so `%I` is resolved:

>>> for %I in (.) do @echo %I
.

>>> rem // escaping does not help, `%I` is still resolved:

>>> for %I in (.) do @(echo ^%I & echo %^I & echo ^%^I & echo %%I)
.
.
.
%.
```

And in a batch file...:

```cmd
@echo off & rem // Here you need to double the `%` signs!
rem // `echo` is outside of `for` scope, so this works:
echo %%I & echo %%%%I
echo/
rem // `echo` is inside of `for` scope, so `%%I` is resolved:
for %%I in (.) do (echo %%I & echo %%%%I)
echo/
rem // escaping does not help, `%%I` is still resolved:
for %%I in (.) do (echo ^%%I & echo %%^I & echo ^%%^I & echo ^%^%I & echo ^%^%^I & echo ^%%^%%^I)
```

...the result is:

> ```cmd
> %I
> %%I
>
> .
> %.
>
> .
> .
> .
> I
> ^I
> %.
> ```

So how do I have to change the above approaches (both `cmd` and batch file) to get `%I` echoed?

Comment: This is an interesting Q&A to know about, but isn't it a manufactured problem? Surely the simplest solution is to avoid choosing the same letter for your 'for' loop - you have 25 other letters to choose (plus all 26 of the opposite case), so why choose the only one that gives you problems?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, of course this is a constructed problem, but I found it interesting to solve, and I wanted to share it. Actually I encountered such unwanted `%I` expansion while trying something like this: `for %I in (.) do @(set "ITEM=%I" & call echo ^%ITEM^%)` (returns `.TEM%`, because `%I` in `^%ITEM^%` is expanded)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to work around the unintended expansion of the `for` reference `%I`:

#### Delayed Expansion

In `cmd`:

```
>>> rem // Ensure that delayed expansion is enabled!

>>> set "STR=%I"

>>> echo !STR!
%I

>>> for %I in (.) do @echo !STR!
%I
```

In a batch file...:

```
@echo off & rem // Here you need to double the `%` signs!
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "STR=%%I"
echo !STR!
for %%I in (.) do echo !STR!

set "STR=%%%%I"
echo !STR!
for %%I in (.) do echo !STR!
endlocal
```

...with the result:

> ```
> %I
> %I
> %%I
> %%I
> ```

However, delayed expansion could harm under certain circumstances; so could the environment localisation done by `setlocal`/`endlocal`.

But there is still another way:

#### Wrap Around Another `for` Loop

In `cmd`:

```
>>> for %J in (%I) do @echo %J
%I

>>> for %J in (%I) do @for %I in (.) do @echo %J
%I
```

In a batch-file...:

```
@echo off & rem // Here you need to double the `%` signs!
for %%J in (%%I) do (
    echo %%J
    for %%I in (.) do echo %%J
)
for %%J in (%%%%I) do (
    echo %%J
    for %%I in (.) do echo %%J
)
```

...with the result:

> ```
> %I
> %I
> %%I
> %%I
> ```

Although you cannot echo `%%J` now any more, of course.

#### Wrap Around Another `for` Loop (edited according to [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365237/how-to-securely-echo-literal-string-i#comment69959482_41365238))

In `cmd`:

```
>>> for %J in (%) do @echo %JI
%I

>>> for %J in (%) do @for %I in (.) do @echo %JI
%I
```

In a batch-file...:

```
@echo off & rem // Here you need to double the `%` signs!
for %%J in (%%) do (
    echo %%JI
    for %%I in (.) do echo %%JI
)
for %%J in (%%%%) do (
    echo %%JI
    for %%I in (.) do echo %%JI
)
```

...with the result:

> ```
> %I
> %I
> %%I
> %%I
> ```

This time even `%%J` could be echoed.

Comment: +1, but I suggest defining `%J` as a single `%`, without a letter. Then `%J` can be used wherever a `%` literal is needed.

Comment: Good idea, @dbenham, this is for sure more flexible! you could also provide your own answer if you want...